# What's the difference between id and localId in Apache Royale?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, apache-royale

In Apache Royale we can identify objects with "`id`" and "`localId`" properties. The problem is to know why we have two ways of doing the same apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the Answer and sharing solution:

HTML requires ID's that are unique, so by creating Royale components that internally use ID's to identify the inner sub-components this means the same ID will be used in all instances created and therefore generating a problem of *lack of uniqueness*.

**Solution**: 
Use "`localId`" in the inner components, so Royale will use it internally and will avoid to add "`id`" when you transpile to HTML.